# Append list items with different query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nav list generated by a CMS. The cms does not allow for additional html to be inserted in the nav component except adding a class to each element. The end product I would like to have is attaching an icon beside each nav item via font awesome. Each nav item has its own unique icon and unique class. I have been able to use jquery to append each one individually however is there a cleaner approach to this.

.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="homeNav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="aboutNav"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="objNav"><a href="#objective">Objective</a></li>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

.jquery i am using

```
$('.homeNav').children().empty().append('<i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home');
```

Should I just make a jquery call for each item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an object mapping the `className` to the icon class, eg:

```
var icons = {
  'homeNav': 'fa-home',
  'aboutNav': 'fa-about',
  'objNav' : 'fa-objective'
};
```

Then set the html of each `navbar` `<li>`:

```
$('.nav.navbar-nav li').html(function(i, text) {
  return '<i class="fa ' + icons[this.className] + '">' + $(this).text();
});
```

You'd probably need to add some checks in there to make sure that `icons[this.className]` exists, but this should point you in the right direction.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZNeg/5/)

#### edit

If you need to keep the anchors:

```
$('.nav.navbar-nav li').html(function(i, text) {
  return $('a', this).prepend('<i class="fa ' + icons[this.className] + '">');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create object of all your images to be added like this

```
 var images = {
        homeNav: '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>',
        aboutNav: '<i class="fa fa-about"></i>',
    };
```

Then use jquery each to iterate over [**each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) li and add child to link inside like this

```
  $('.navbar-nav li').each(function () {
        var cl = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).find('a').append(images[cl]);
    });
```

If you want to append it to li itself then use `$(this).append(images[cl]);`

If you want to remove the link but keep its text and add your element, use this

```
$('.navbar-nav li').each(function () {
     var elm = $(this);
     var cl = elm.attr('class');
     elm.html(images[cl] + elm.find('a').html());
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/X9ec2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think the most cleaner approach will be using the class of each "li" and insert the icon through CSS instead of adding lines of jquery to append an element. You can use CSS image sprite and change the background-position for each "li".

Comment: Problem with this is I am not using images. The icons are actually fonts from font awesome [link](http://fontawesome.io)

Comment: If you follow the awesome link...you can see that they are not using any JS too...they are using CSS ":before" and "content" and the importing the font.